# Get a break down of partitions and total diskdrive size using get-wmiobject -class win32_diskdrive

Tags: powershell

I can return the total size of the disk drive and number of partitions quite easily using

> get-wmiobject -class win32_diskdrive | select size, partitions

but how do I return the breakdown of partitions and the total disk drive?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "breakdown of partitions" and "total disk drive"?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `Win32_DiskPartition` class.  It gives more information about each partition.